# How to find the probability of an estimator?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I'm working on some homework and am having a hard time finding the probability of an estimator. The question says that $Y_i$ ~ Bernoulli($p_2$), where $p_2 = 0.1$. The estimator $p_2 = \bar{Y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ and $n = 86$.

The probability distribution of the estimator is $P(S = s) = \frac{86!}{s!(86-s)!}(0.1)^s(0.9)^{86-s}$

and $S$ ~ Binomial$(86,p_2)$

a. If $p_2 = 0.1$, what is the probability that the estimator is less than or equal to 0.05.

b. If $p_2 = 0.1$, is observing the estimator greater than 0.2 a likely event?

As a side note, I'm using R to calculate these values. For part a, I know that $P(\bar{Y} \leq 0.05) = P(\frac{S}{86} \leq 0.05)$. Since S ~ Binomial$(86,0.1)$, should I be calculating that and then finding the probability that it is less than or equal to 0.05? I don't know how that would make sense though.

Otherwise, what equation should I be using to get this probability? In R would this be `pbinom(0.05,86,1)`?

For part b, is it just asking for $P(\bar{Y} > 0.2)$? If so can I just do `1 - pbinom(0.2,86,1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminology and notation are a bit strange.
First, $p_2,$ which I'll call just $p,$ is a *parameter,* not an
estimator.

The number of successes in $n = 86$ Bernoulli
trials is $S = \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i,$ which has the distribution
$Binom(86,p),$ as you say.

The *estimator* of $p$ is $\hat p = S/n = \bar Y.$

**(a)** If $p = .1,$ what is 
$P(\bar Y = S/86 \le 0.05) = P(S \le 4.3) = P(S \le 4) = F_S(4),$ where
$F_S$ is the CDF (cumulative distribution function) of $S.$ In R, this is found with any one of
four expressions:

```
 > pbinom(4, 86, .1)         # 'pbinom' is the CDF
 [1] 0.06034351
 > sum(dbinom(0:4, 86, .1))  # 'dbinom' is the PDF
 [1] 0.06034351
 > pbinom(4.3, 86, .1)
 [1] 0.06034351
 > pbinom(86*.05, 86, .1)
 [1] 0.06034351
```

**(b)** If $p = .1,$ what is $P(\bar Y > .2)\,?$ In R this is found as follows:

```
 > 1 - pbinom(86*.2, 86, .1)
 [1] 0.001914072
 > sum(dbinom(18:86, 86, .1))
 [1]  0.001914072
```

***Addendum:*** These exercises seem to be probing the lower and upper
tail probabilities of $Binom(86,.1),$ which has mean $\mu = np = 8.6$ and SD $\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)} = 2.7821.$
The Empirical Rule (ER), based on *normal* distributions, says that
about 95% of the probability of a distribution tends to lie between
$\mu \pm 2\sigma.$ Your distribution is hardly normal, but the
ER works pretty well for a surprising variety of non-normal distributions,
including yours.

```
 > n = 86;  p = .1;  pm = c(0,1)
 > mu = n*p;  sigma = sqrt(n*p*(1-p))
 > mu; sigma
 [1] 8.6
 [1] 2.782086
 > mu + pm*2*sigma
 [1]  3.035829 14.164171
 > sum(dbinom(4:14, 86, .1))
 [1] 0.9542092
```

Comment: How did the parameter $p$ change from 0.1 to 0.01? Also for part B, why are we finding the $P(\bar{Y} > 0.02)$ and not $P(\bar{Y} > 0.2)$?

Comment: Written too late at night, I guess. Thanks for the heads up. OK now, I hope. Included an addendum on a related topic.